# Kendo Grid sorting a different order

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

We have a column being displayed in text, however the sort over should be numeric.

Is it possible for order a sortable column in the Kendo UI grid by a customisable order, in my case by a numeric field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the sortable.compare-function of the column: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.sortable.compare

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
var numbers = {
    "one"  : "a",
    "two"  : "b",
    "three": "c"
};

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { id: 1, item: "two" },
        { id: 2, item: "one" },
        { id: 3, item: "three" }
    ]
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    sortable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "item",
        sortable: {
            compare: function(a, b) {
                if (numbers[a.item] > numbers[b.item]) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (numbers[a.item] < numbers[b.item]) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    // the characters are equal.
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }]
});
```